# Make coupon entry in commerce server required before a discount is applied, possible?

Tags: commerceserver2007, microsoft-commerce-server

I have created a discount in commerce server, and linked it with a list of **private** coupons. The problem is that after running the basket pipline it applies this discount even though no coupon was ever entered. It seems to me me this should be the default behavior when you create a discount which contains a list of coupons. There does not appear to be any obvious way of doing this.

My question is how do you make the coupons the condition to apply a given discount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fumbling around for a few hours, I figured out why this was happening to me. My issue was not caused because of the default commerce server behavior. If this ever happens to you, here is the fix. In the basket pipline file make sure you add the stages of: ***"Commerce Reserve Promotion Codes"*** before ***"OrderDiscount"*** and make sure you have **"Commerce Record Promotion Codes"** before ***"RequiredOrderAdjustPriceCy"*** but after ***"OrderLevelDiscountApply"***. Alternatively download the StarterSite project from microsoft and use the basket pipline from there.